# Are there any "Enrich processor" alternatives for OpenSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

My scenario:

These are my indexes on the OpenSearch cluster

1. posts
2. likes

Requirement:

When I query for a post I should also be able to enrich or populate the obtained documents with their respective likes, which are stored in another index (*likes*).

As per my research, it is possible to achieve this with Elasticsearch using an enrich processor, but such a thing is not available in OpenSearch.

I am new to both Elasticsearch and OpenSearch. Please suggest to me any possible solutions.

Comment: Hi, Did you find anyway?

Comment: Hey hi, no sadly didn't find anyway to achieve that and i ended up nesting the documents.